# Using binfmt-misc in conjunction with xattrs

Tags: command-line, bash, filesystem, security

I currently use a piece of sandboxing software on my 14.04 machine that isolates Linux binaries from one another (Using a special type of namespace isolation different than AppArmor)

Currently, the way to invoke the sandbox is like so:

```
/usr/local/bin/sandbox /path/to/binary --optional-arguments
```

My problem is, I want to invoke certain arbitrary binaries and have them execute in the sandbox ***without*** having to prepend the `/usr/local/bin/sandbox` portion to my shell command. I.e.:

```
/usr/local/bin/sandbox /path/to/binary --optional-arguments --> *new process*
```

Becomes:

```
/path/to/binary --optional-arguments --> *binfmt-misc* --> *new process*
```

I figured that I could easily do this thanks to binfmt-misc, however after reading through the documentation it only seems to support requesting an interpreter through either magic bits in the file itself or through its file extension. As it is not feesable to do any of those things in this specific case, I looked for an option in binfmt-misc that could allow me to specify extended attributes on certain binaries that I want launched in the sandbox that binfmt-misc could then read and use to determine that these binaries must be run by the `/usr/local/bin/sandbox` "interpreter." However, I have yet to find such a feature in it that would allow me to do so.

Is there any way that I can achieve launching arbitrary ELF binaries with no extension compiled for the same architecture as my computer using the sandbox automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this through binfmt-misc and xattrs, but I'll propose a different approach. I haven't tried it out but I can't see why it wouldn't work.

The idea is to use a [union mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) to hide the real binaries by a wrapper script that calls the sandbox. We need a union mount where the upper directory is mostly read and writes to a non-shadowed file go to the lower directory, which is not supported by all union mount systems.  In particular this rules out OverlayFS which is now built into the Linux kernel.

Write a generic wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/bin/sandbox "${0#/sandboxed}" "$@"
```

Create a directory `/sandbox` and create a union mount that shadows the root filesystem. I'll use [aufs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) (Ubuntu: [`aufs-tools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/aufs-tools)), which unfortunately has recently been abandoned; there may be a better choice.

```
mount -t aufs -o br:/,br:/sandbox aufs-sandbox /
```

For each executable that you want to sandbox, link `/sandbox/path/to/foo` to the wrapper script (after creating the necessary directories `/path/to` under `/sandbox`).

Comment: Hmm, that's a unique solution to the problem! Unless somebody has an easier method I'll mark this as accepted